# How to remove element from specific div using turbo stream?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

I have a page with 3 divs milestones, achievedMilestones, inProgressMilestones

There is an action to change the status of the milestones to switch between both statuses.

This is the view

```
  <div id="milestones" class="hidden p-4 flex flex-col gap-y-3" data-tabs-target="panel">
    <%= render @goal.milestones %>
  </div>
  <div id="achievedMilestones" class="hidden p-4 flex flex-col gap-y-3">
    <%= render @goal.milestones.where(status: 'achieved') %>
  </div>
  <div id="inProgressMilestones" class="hidden p-4 flex flex-col gap-y-3">
    <%= render @goal.milestones.where(status: 'in_progress') %>
  </div>
```

This is the controller action

```
  def update_progress
    @milestone.update_progress(params[:status])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream do
        if params[:status] == "achieved"
          render turbo_stream: [
            turbo_stream.prepend("achievedMilestones", @milestone),
            turbo_stream.replace(@milestone, partial: 'milestone', locals: { milestone: @milestone })
          ]
        elsif params[:status] == "in_progress"
          render turbo_stream: [
            turbo_stream.prepend("inProgressMilestones", @milestone),
            turbo_stream.replace(@milestone, partial: 'milestone', locals: { milestone: @milestone })
          ]
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to remove the element from its old div to the correct one without removing it from the milestones div like

```
     turbo_stream.remove("#achievedMilestones #milestone_#{@milestone.id}"),
```

or should I simply use StimulusJS

Answer (score 0):

Can you also share `_milestone.html.erb` file,

Probably you can also send string local to `_milestone` partial for different statuses:

```
<%= render @goal.milestones.where(status: 'achieved'), locals: { parent_id: 'achievedMilestones' } %>
```

and inject that in dom_id like => `#{parentId}_#{milestone.id}`
in _milestone.html.erb

```
<div id='<%= "#{parent_id}_#{milestone.id}" %>'>
```

Now you can use this div element in turbo_stream:

```
turbo_stream.remove("#achievedMilestones_#{@milestone.id}")
```